# About measures acting on measurable functions.

Tags: measure-theory, markov-chains, markov-process

If $\phi : X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a measurable function and $\mu$ is a measure on $X$ then what is $``\mu(\phi)"$?

Is this a notation for some function?

---

I came across this notation for the first time in Theorem 1.2 (page 2) stated in these lectures, 
http://www.hairer.org/papers/harris.pdf

Comment: Well, in the reference I cited, the measure is denoted as $\mu_*$ itself. I dont think its a pushforward in this context. There is no $\mu$ defined in the linked lecture notes.

Answer (score -1):

It is simply the integral of $\phi$ with respect to the measure $\mu$, that is $\mu(\phi) := \int_X \phi(x) \mu(dx)$

Hence, you can see the measure $\mu$ as a linear function from the set of measurable functions on $X$ to $[0,\infty]$

Comment: Well, then does the statement of Theorem 1.2 make sense? Because there it seems then that the LHS is measuring the distance of a function, ``$P^n \phi$" from a constant $\mu(\phi)$, thats odd?

Comment: $\mathcal{P}^n$ is the n-step transition kernel. Indeed, technically $\mathcal{P}^n \varphi $ is actually a function of $x$, which at the same time represents the initial point of the chain. To be precise, the definition is $\mathcal{P}^n \varphi(x) = \int_X \varphi(y) \mathcal{P}^n(x,dy)$. The norm in just before the theorem is defined as the sup over x, so the dependence on x goes away

Comment: Well,  if we defined $\mu(\phi)$ like what you are defining, then $\mu(\phi)$ does not have any dependence on $x$ to even begin with! So it is a distance measure of a function from a constant?

Comment: Yes, it has no dependence on $x$, so it is the constant function. Still, the definition of the $\|\cdot\|$  applies as usual, just subtract the constant $\mu_\star(\phi)$ from $\mathcal{P}^n \varphi(x)$. The theorem then pertains to the decay of this function in the $\|\cdot\|$ norm defined above it.